# How to decode this url (combination of Base64 and UTF8)?

Tags: javascript, url, utf-8, base64

I have come across an url that I need to decode.

After trying multiple base64 (utf8), and JS url decoders online, it doesn't help, though the latter did work to an extent.

The url is;

> starplayer://%3Curl%3Ebolwl6pIrBrL1GEf7V%2F5Uy6eoFPW77xb5jrS%2BCqRb3%2BoaVq%2Fm3REcqkDQzNsEu2JH6Q2ysUzG73Is93y%2FhmRNK10znrzHKOmEcFITgVDIQeGRVDk7iMBeDth%2BNzmZLIK1yDadYIyBvUPAJ4JRiHzevUVOQ8FMVUJzWAtA5qONGf40KaP31iKvMICFJ3lRjI1cuclOg4KxDo8GeQfmsS7xCAbX1XSWMNlEQ%2Fqzaaht2Gj1fWfbgo%2FsJbGVGSr5swv7ezk4S77LV%2BLpT%2FGbRLbovv0X%2BE4bAQFBtbxfsJ%2BjRU%3D%3Cbase_url%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.etoosindia.com%2F%3Cwidth%3E720%3Cheight%3E500%3Ctopmost%3Etrue%3Cresizing%3Eundefined%3Ccookie%3EX2dhPUdBMS4yLjM2NzU5MzMwNS4xNDk4MjExMjczOyBjb29raWVfdWlkPTsgbWVtX25tPVpHOXVkQ0JqWVd4czsgbWVtX2lkPVoyeHdaM1ZvWkdOQWMyaGhjbXRzWVhObGNuTXVZMjl0OyBtZW1fY2Q9TnpreU1EVTU7IF9femxjbWlkPWhBZ1hnVGM4bU1Iekxl%3Ccaption%3ERXRvb3MlMjBJbmRpYQ%3D%3D

After putting the above into a url decoder, I got;
  `starplayer://<url>bolwl6pIrBrL1GEf7V/5Uy6eoFPW77xb5jrS+CqRb3+oaVq/m3REcqkDQzNsEu2JH6Q2ysUzG73Is93y/hmRNK10znrzHKOmEcFITgVDIQeGRVDk7iMBeDth+NzmZLIK1yDadYIyBvUPAJ4JRiHzevUVOQ8FMVUJzWAtA5qONGf40KaP31iKvMICFJ3lRjI1cuclOg4KxDo8GeQfmsS7xCAbX1XSWMNlEQ/qzaaht2Gj1fWfbgo/sJbGVGSr5swv7ezk4S77LV+LpT/GbRLbovv0X+E4bAQFBtbxfsJ+jRU=<base_url>http://www.etoosindia.com/<width>720<height>500<topmost>true<resizing>undefined<cookie>X2dhPUdBMS4yLjM2NzU5MzMwNS4xNDk4MjExMjczOyBjb29raWVfdWlkPTsgbWVtX25tPVpHOXVkQ0JqWVd4czsgbWVtX2lkPVoyeHdaM1ZvWkdOQWMyaGhjbXRzWVhObGNuTXVZMjl0OyBtZW1fY2Q9TnpreU1EVTU7IF9femxjbWlkPWhBZ1hnVGM4bU1Iekxl<caption>RXRvb3MlMjBJbmRpYQ==`

The above url was decoded by a script I am attaching below (see end);

```
var STARPLAYER_EXE_NOT_INSTALLED = "The StarPlayer is not installed.";
var STARPLAYER_EXE_WANT_TO_INSTALL = "Do you want to install?";
var STARPLAYER_UNKNOWN_INSTALLED = "Has the StarPlayer is running normally?";
var StarPlayerExe = {};
StarPlayerExe.run = function() {
    if (typeof this.url == "undefined") {
        alert("undefined url");
        return
    }
    var a = this;
    StarPlayerLaunchUri(a.getUrl(), function() {
        a.result(true, a.install)
    }, function() {
        a.result(false, a.install)
    }, function() {
        a.unKnownResult(a.install)
    })
}
;
function base_url() {
    var b = location.protocol;
    var a = location.host;
    return b + "//" + a + "/"
}
StarPlayerExe.getUrl = function() {
    var a = "<url>" + this.url + "<base_url>" + base_url() + "<width>" + this.width + "<height>" + this.height + "<topmost>" + this.topmost + "<resizing>" + this.resizing + "<cookie>" + Base64.encode(document.cookie) + "<caption>" + Base64.encode(encodeURIComponent(this.caption));
    return "starplayer://" + encodeURIComponent(a)
}
;
StarPlayerExe.result = function(a, c) {
    if (a == false) {
        var b = confirm(STARPLAYER_EXE_NOT_INSTALLED + "\n" + STARPLAYER_EXE_WANT_TO_INSTALL);
        if (b == true) {
            window.location.href = c
        }
    }
}
;
StarPlayerExe.unKnownResult = function(b) {
    if (COOKIE.get("starplayer_installed") != "true") {
        var a = confirm(STARPLAYER_UNKNOWN_INSTALLED);
        if (a == true) {
            COOKIE.set("starplayer_installed", "true", 60)
        } else {
            window.location.href = b
        }
    }
}
;
function StarPlayerLaunchUri(g, d, b, o) {
    var s, k, a, j, n, l, m, h, r;
    function f(e) {
        if (typeof e === "function") {
            e()
        }
    }
    function p(t) {
        var e;
        if (!t) {
            t = document.body
        }
        e = document.createElement("iframe");
        e.style.display = "none";
        t.appendChild(e);
        return e
    }
    function c(e) {
        if (!j) {
            return
        }
        if (!e) {
            e = document.body
        }
        e.removeChild(j);
        j = null
    }
    var i = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Edge/12") != -1 ? true : false;
    r = {
        isChrome: false,
        isFirefox: false,
        isIE: false,
        isSafari: false
    };
    if (window.chrome && !navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera|OPR\//)) {
        r.isChrome = true
    } else {
        if (typeof InstallTrigger !== "undefined") {
            r.isFirefox = true
        } else {
            if (i || "ActiveXObject"in window) {
                r.isIE = true
            } else {
                if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Safari\//)) {
                    r.isSafari = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (navigator.msLaunchUri) {
        navigator.msLaunchUri(g, d, b)
    } else {
        if (r.isChrome || r.isSafari) {
            m = function() {
                window.clearTimeout(l);
                window.removeEventListener("blur", m);
                f(d)
            }
            ;
            h = function() {
                window.removeEventListener("blur", m);
                f(b)
            }
            ;
            window.addEventListener("blur", m);
            l = window.setTimeout(h, 1000);
            window.location.href = g
        } else {
            if (r.isFirefox) {
                j = p();
                try {
                    j.contentWindow.location.href = g;
                    f(d)
                } catch (q) {
                    if (q.name === "NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL") {
                        f(b)
                    } else {
                        f(o)
                    }
                } finally {
                    c()
                }
            } else {
                if (r.isIE) {
                    a = window.open("", "launcher", "width=0,height=0");
                    a.location.href = g;
                    try {
                        a.location.href = "about:blank";
                        f(d);
                        n = window.setInterval(function() {
                            a.close();
                            if (a.closed) {
                                window.clearInterval(n)
                            }
                        }, 500)
                    } catch (q) {
                        a = window.open("about:blank", "launcher");
                        a.close();
                        f(b)
                    }
                } else {
                    j = p();
                    j.contentWindow.location.href = g;
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        c(k);
                        f(o)
                    }, 1000)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
var COOKIE = {
    set: function(g, b, d, c) {
        var a = new Date();
        var f;
        switch (c) {
        case "day":
            a.setDate(a.getDate() + d);
            break;
        case "hour":
            a.setTime(a.getTime() + (d * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            break;
        default:
            a.setDate(a.getDate() + d)
        }
        if (d) {
            f = escape(b) + "; expires=" + a.toGMTString()
        } else {
            f = escape(b)
        }
        document.cookie = g + "=" + f + "; path=/"
    },
    get: function(g) {
        var e = document.cookie.split(";");
        var d, c, f, b, a;
        b = e.length;
        for (d = 0; d < b; d++) {
            a = e[d].indexOf("=");
            c = e[d].substr(0, a);
            f = e[d].substr(a + 1);
            c = c.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (c == g) {
                return unescape(f)
            }
        }
    },
    del: function(a) {
        this.set(a, "", -1)
    }
};
var Base64 = {
    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
    encode: function(c) {
        var a = "";
        var k, h, f, j, g, e, d;
        var b = 0;
        c = Base64._utf8_encode(c);
        while (b < c.length) {
            k = c.charCodeAt(b++);
            h = c.charCodeAt(b++);
            f = c.charCodeAt(b++);
            j = k >> 2;
            g = ((k & 3) << 4) | (h >> 4);
            e = ((h & 15) << 2) | (f >> 6);
            d = f & 63;
            if (isNaN(h)) {
                e = d = 64
            } else {
                if (isNaN(f)) {
                    d = 64
                }
            }
            a = a + this._keyStr.charAt(j) + this._keyStr.charAt(g) + this._keyStr.charAt(e) + this._keyStr.charAt(d)
        }
        return a
    },
    decode: function(c) {
        var a = "";
        var k, h, f;
        var j, g, e, d;
        var b = 0;
        c = c.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
        while (b < c.length) {
            j = this._keyStr.indexOf(c.charAt(b++));
            g = this._keyStr.indexOf(c.charAt(b++));
            e = this._keyStr.indexOf(c.charAt(b++));
            d = this._keyStr.indexOf(c.charAt(b++));
            k = (j << 2) | (g >> 4);
            h = ((g & 15) << 4) | (e >> 2);
            f = ((e & 3) << 6) | d;
            a = a + String.fromCharCode(k);
            if (e != 64) {
                a = a + String.fromCharCode(h)
            }
            if (d != 64) {
                a = a + String.fromCharCode(f)
            }
        }
        a = Base64._utf8_decode(a);
        return a
    },
    _utf8_encode: function(b) {
        b = b.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var a = "";
        for (var e = 0; e < b.length; e++) {
            var d = b.charCodeAt(e);
            if (d < 128) {
                a += String.fromCharCode(d)
            } else {
                if ((d > 127) && (d < 2048)) {
                    a += String.fromCharCode((d >> 6) | 192);
                    a += String.fromCharCode((d & 63) | 128)
                } else {
                    a += String.fromCharCode((d >> 12) | 224);
                    a += String.fromCharCode(((d >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                    a += String.fromCharCode((d & 63) | 128)
                }
            }
        }
        return a
    },
    _utf8_decode: function(a) {
        var b = "";
        var d = 0;
        var e = c1 = c2 = 0;
        while (d < a.length) {
            e = a.charCodeAt(d);
            if (e < 128) {
                b += String.fromCharCode(e);
                d++
            } else {
                if ((e > 191) && (e < 224)) {
                    c2 = a.charCodeAt(d + 1);
                    b += String.fromCharCode(((e & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                    d += 2
                } else {
                    c2 = a.charCodeAt(d + 1);
                    c3 = a.charCodeAt(d + 2);
                    b += String.fromCharCode(((e & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                    d += 3
                }
            }
        }
        return b
    }
};
```

Can the above code be used to decode this url, and if so, how?

If anyone can help me decode this, I would be very thankful.

Comment: put some effort into this. Right there in the middle is the code that builds this url from its pieces. So wherever this is running, it already has the decoded pieces

Comment: @Thomas If we take a look at the text that the URL decoder gave me, and the code that tells me that the above code was built by <url>+<base url>+other. However, if I put the string between <url> and <base url> , it turns out to be an error in the decoder. I have also tried omitting the slashes first, but in vain. If we take the string decoded, then the full url would be <base url>+<url>, but it gives a 404